# Check if user exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, exists

I have a problem i dont know why this dont run

```
$fb_id = $db->real_escape_string($fb_id);
        $result = $db->query("select id,fb_id from users where fb_id='$fb_id'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "user exist";
        } else {
echo "user dont exist";
        }
```

there is one error

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in 94
```

but in line 94 i have

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

thanks for help

Comment: Yes looks like you are using some mysql class for query operation $db is an instance of that class. Check in that class you may have some function to get the num rows something as get_num_rows() and u can use as $db->get_num_rows()...

Comment: when i change it how you say there is no method
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::get_num_rows() in /data/web/virtuals/47683/virtual/www/subdom/test/callback.php on line 94

i use this for connect to db $db = mysqli_connect

Comment: oh you took the literal function name what I mentioned. I asked to check the $db class and see if there is a method to return the number of rows, I just gave u an example.